# pgAdmin in docker not displaying on selected port - after version 4.15

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I am a long time user of pgAdmin in a docker container, I think it's really useful.

Whilst working on site, I have my laptop configured with VirtualBox running a Debian Buster instance so that I can develop locally. The instance has docker installed and runs my own PostgreSQL derived container, pgAdmin, swagger & PostgREST.

I have been using pgAdmin 4.15 but recently tried to upgrade to the pgAdmin 4.25 container image, and from my host Windows box,
http://localhost:5050/browser/
pgAdmin stopped being available.

In parallel, the client is running RHEL 7 with dockerised pgAdmin against a bare metal PostgreSQL 12 installation; likewise I decided to upgrade from 4.15 to 4.25: it too stopped working. I rolled back to 4.15 and it started working again.

My local pgadmin.yml looks like:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  tp-pgadmin:
    container_name: tp-pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.15
    restart: always
    #env_file: env.pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-lol@lol.com}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-lollydoodah}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS:  ${PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS:-0.0.0.0}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    volumes:
       - tp-pgadmin-vol:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:5050"
    depends_on:
      - tp-postgres
    networks:
      - tp-pg-net
    #restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  tp-pg-net:
    external: true
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  tp-pgadmin-vol:
    external: true
```

The customer pgadmin.yaml is very similar (!):

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.15
    #env_file: env.pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-lol@lol.com}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-lollydoodah}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS: ${PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS:-0.0.0.0}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-vol:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:5050"

volumes:
  pgadmin-vol:
    external: true
```

Unsurprisingly changing the 4.15 for 4.25 pulls in the new version, with that as the only change it stops working.

I have played around with the ports, but there was no improvement.

Does anyone have an idea what has changed with pgAdmin between 4.15 and later releases with respect to how it is served?

I can't see anything obvious.

With my best regards, Paul.